# ReactJS app Material UI - iFrame - make labels / texts copyable

Tags: reactjs, iframe, material-ui

I have a ReactJS app that is built with Material UI.
The ReactJS app is embedded in an iFrame (and has to be).

What I Want to achieve is:

It should be possible for users to copy texts. Labels and Paragraphs are not
copyable in the browser if the ReactJS app is embedded in an iFrame.

What can I do to achieve it ?

Comment: What do you mean `are not copyable`? I don't think it has anything with iframe.

Comment: do you want to add a button to copy any text?